# ¿Por qué mis div no se crean de manera ordenada con js?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Estoy haciendo una pagina en la que se cargan artículos desde la base de datos y se muestren en la web, Para obtener el nuevo total de filas que tiene mi base de datos uso ajax y php en el archivo php solo me regresa el numero total de filas y una vez que se verifica que el numero regresado por php no es null o 0 se ejecuta otro php mediante ajax el cual va obteniendo la fila correspondiente a la fila que quiero obtener después creo un array con el resultado y comienzo la construcción de los div o tarjetas en las que se pondrá la información, el problema es que no se crean en orden es decir no llevar el orden de Div1 Div2 Div3 si no que es aleatorio puede ser Div3 Div1 Div2 etc. La verdad es que no entiendo porque hace esto si debería de crearlos conforme a la variable i lo cual las dejaría en el orden correcto espero me puedan ayudar a resolver este problema.
Ejemplo de mi código

```
if(response != 0){

                    FirstPostList = document.getElementById('PostPanelArticle0');

                    if(!FirstPostList){

                        PostCount = response;

                        for(let i = 1; i <= PostCount; i++){
                            
                            let RowToSearchNumber = i;

                            DivMainToPut = document.getElementById('IdContainerArticlesLoaded');
                            DivImageToPut = document.getElementById('IdPostImage' + i);
                            DivInfoToPut = document.getElementById('IdPostInfo' + i);

                            $.ajax(
                                {
                    
                                    url: './php/AppGetArticleInfoPosition.php',
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    data: {
                                        RowToSearch: RowToSearchNumber
                                    },
                                    success: function(response){
                                                                
                                        ResponseFS = response;
                                        
                                        let Array = JSON.parse("[" + ResponseFS + "]");

                                        let PostPhotoURL = Array[0];
                                        let PostTitle = Array[1];
                                        let PostResume = Array[2];
                                        let PostViews = Array[3];
                                        
                                        console.log(PostTitle);
                                        console.log(PostResume);
                                        console.log(PostViews);

                                        const $DivPost = document.createElement('div'),
                                        $DivImagePost = document.createElement('div'),
                                        $ImageDivImagePost = document.createElement('img'),
                                        $DivInfoPost = document.createElement('div'),
                                        $DivTitlePost = document.createElement('p'),
                                        $DivResumePost = document.createElement('p'),
                                        $DivStadisticPost = document.createElement('div'),                                            
                                        $DivStadisticPostShare = document.createElement('p'),
                                        $DivStadisticPostLike = document.createElement('p'),
                                        $DivStadisticPostView = document.createElement('p'),
                                        $DivStadisticPostDelete = document.createElement('p');                                            

                                        $DivPost.setAttribute("class", "PostArticleStudioPanel");
                                        $DivPost.setAttribute("id", "IdPostArticleStudioPanel" + i);
                                        $DivImagePost.setAttribute("class", "PostImage");
                                        $DivImagePost.setAttribute("id", "IdPostArticleStudioPanel" + i);
                                        $ImageDivImagePost.setAttribute("src", PostPhotoURL);
                                        $DivInfoPost.setAttribute("class", "PostInfo");
                                        $DivTitlePost.setAttribute("id", "PostTitle");
                                        $DivTitlePost.innerText = PostTitle;
                                        $DivResumePost.setAttribute("id", "PostResume");
                                        $DivResumePost.innerText = PostResume;
                                        $DivStadisticPost.setAttribute("class", "PostStadistic");
                                        $DivStadisticPostShare.setAttribute("id", "IdCompartir");
                                        $DivStadisticPostShare.innerText = "Compartir";
                                        $DivStadisticPostLike.setAttribute("id", "Idlikes");
                                        $DivStadisticPostLike.innerText = "35" + " Likes";
                                        $DivStadisticPostView.setAttribute("id", "IdViews");
                                        $DivStadisticPostView.innerText = PostViews + " Vistas";
                                        $DivStadisticPostDelete.setAttribute("id", "IdDelte");
                                        $DivStadisticPostDelete.innerText = "Eliminar";

                                        $DivImagePost.appendChild($ImageDivImagePost);
                                        $DivPost.appendChild($DivImagePost);
                                        $DivPost.appendChild($DivInfoPost);
                                        $DivPost.appendChild($DivInfoPost);
                                        $DivPost.appendChild($DivStadisticPost);
                                        $DivInfoPost.appendChild($DivTitlePost);
                                        $DivInfoPost.appendChild($DivResumePost);
                                        $DivPost.appendChild($DivStadisticPost);
                                        $DivStadisticPost.appendChild($DivStadisticPostShare);
                                        $DivStadisticPost.appendChild($DivStadisticPostLike);
                                        $DivStadisticPost.appendChild($DivStadisticPostView);
                                        $DivStadisticPost.appendChild($DivStadisticPostDelete);
                                        DivMainToPut.appendChild($DivPost);

                                                                            
                                    },
                                    dataType: 'text'
                                }
                            );

                        }

                    }


                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ajax es asíncrono. El navegador lanza una petición y continúa ejecutándose sin esperar respuesta, cuando le llegue ya ejecutará la función que le pasas con la llamada.

Así que tu bucle principal lanza las n peticiones una detrás de otra; cuando envía la 2 no tiene porqué haber recibido la respuesta a la petición 1. No hay garantía de que la respuesta 1 llegue antes de la 2, ni siquiera hay garantía de que si la respuesta 1 llega antes de la 2 se ejecutará antes la función de la llamada 1.

Soluciones:

- Como llamas al API para todos los valores desde 1 a *RowToSearch*, lo más elegante sería, si se puede, modificar la API para que añadir un método al que solo le indiques  el rango de filas a buscar y te lo devuelva todo en una única llamada.

  Esto también debería ser bastante más eficiente, sobre todo si el número de filas es largo, al reducir el número de peticiones.
- Si eso no se puede, modificando solo el JS, haz que tus funciones no modifiquen directamente el HTML, sino que:

  - guarden los resultados en un array común, y luego
  - verifiquen si todos los elementos ya están y, si es así, modifiquen el HTML con todos los datos a la vez.